# Fetch the locale of laravel app

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, locale, momentjs

I can fetch the locale app in blade like this `{{ config('app.locale') }}`, however, I want to be able to fetch the locale in javascript, specifically in Vue in order to pass it to `moment().locale()` I tried the following on the view home.blade.php it didn't work

```
moment().locale( {{ config('app.locale') }}
```

How can I fetch the locale app in Vue?

Comment: What output do you get from the blade template?  Are you missing quotes around the locale perhaps?

Comment: You're missing a `)` there. Also, where/how do you call that line? And I *think* it should be `@{{ config('app.locale'}}`

Comment: with the current code, in blade it gets converted to `moment().locale( en )`. You need quote/double quote around **en**, so use `moment().locale( "{{ config('app.locale')" }})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Lang;

$locale = Lang::locale(); (gives you the locale detected on the frontend)
$locale = Lang::getLocale(); (gives you the locale set default in the config)
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 4):

You would have to set that value on the window. You could create a script tag in your blade template that creates global variables on the window that you could access.

You could also use https://packagist.org/packages/laracasts/utilities in controller functions that render your view to pass the values to the window with something like this:

```
JavaScript::put(['locale' => config('app.locale')]);
```

And then access it in your JS at `window.locale`

Comment: Great answer! To add to it, you can read about different methods of accessing server side variables with vue at https://zaengle.com/blog/layers-of-a-laravel-vue-application

Comment: That's a great approach.  I generally create meta tags `<meta name="locale" content="Some/Locale">` and grab them with javascript when I need them but this is so much cleaner!